# argparse python two optionals in one variable

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program with the following arguments:

1. File
2. Directory
3. Name1
4. Name2

File must be always passed as argument, directory may or not, and name1 and name2 must be passed none of them or both of them at the same time.

This is what I have at this moment:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("file", help="The file")
parser.add_argument("resources_dir", default='.', nargs='?', help="The directory of media files")
parser.add_argument("name", nargs=2, help="names")
```

Help is showing:

> usage: wacv [-h] file [resources_dir] names names

And I want it to be:

> Usage: wacv file [res_dir] [name1 name2]

But I want the 'name' argument to be like I told before. How can I achieve this?

Comment: assuming `names` are just strings, how do you expect the parser to decide if `name1` is not the optional `res_dir` (assuming a `res_dir` has not been provided)? There is no way to force `0 or 2` semantics directly with `argparse` but you can accept `*` and then do your own error checking.

Comment: Finally what I decided is to accept * on names and after check for myself if is 0 or 2, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use

```
(`--names`, nargs=2)
```

That makes them optional, but if provided, it requires 2.  Also it separates those 2 strings from the optional one for `"resources_dir".

You could use `nargs='*'`, allowing 0, 1 or more.  But 2 strings would be allocated to `file`, `dir`; 3 to file, dir, and one to names, etc.  In other words it can't tell, by content, whether an optional string belongs to `dir` or to `names`.  It goes strictly by position.

In any case there isn't a `0 or 2 nargs`, except as I suggests above.

Comment: Good solution. I was looking for something like that. I still think its a little weird to do it like that, but it works.